# Oracle : How to update column of a partitioned table

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, partitioning

My requirement is to update `partition_date` column of a already partitioned table - `MYTABLE`.
I have `MYPROC` pl/sql procedure to do this.
Below is the relevant content of `MYPROC`.

```
p_partition_name VARCHAR2(40);

SELECT distinct(uo.subobject_name)
INTO p_partition_name
FROM MYTABLE  t,
  user_objects uo
WHERE dbms_rowid.rowid_object(t.rowid) = uo.object_id
AND partition_date BETWEEN '01-OCT-2015' AND '31-OCT-2015';



BEGIN

                         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Partition Name' || p_partition_name);
                           FOR i IN 1 .. partition_table.count
                             LOOP
                                UPDATE MYTABLE partition (p_partition_name) SET PARTITION_DATE = '01-AUG-2015' WHERE {..some condition..}
                             END LOOP; 
                      END;
```

When I execute `MYPROC`, I get below error.

```
Error report:
ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist
ORA-06512: at "NESSDBA.MYPROC", line 116
ORA-06512: at line 2
02149. 00000 -  "Specified partition does not exist"
*Cause:    Partition not found for the object.
*Action:   Retry with correct partition name.
Partition NameSYS_P3495
```

When I issue the below plain `update` statement without using procedure and by manually passing partition name, there are no errors.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE partition (SYS_P3495) SET PARTITION_DATE = '01-AUG-2015' WHERE {..some condition..}
```

How to pass partition name to my update statement in pl/sql?

Comment: Is there some reason that you need to specify the partition name?  That is almost never necessary.  If you wanted to use the partition name and determine the partition name at runtime, then your procedure would need to use dynamic SQL to construct the statement.  That's possible but it adds quite a bit of complexity and it seems unlikely that it is really necessary.

Comment: I am running `update` statement with partition name to improve performance of `update` command. I read this some where as well. I even noticed the time taken by running plain `update` statement vs `update` statement with partition name. There is a big difference in time taken. BTW I have millions of records in my table.

Comment: Does your statement use the partition key in the where clause?  Could it?  It seems unlikely that you can determine the name of the partition that has the data you are interested but that the partition key would not be one of the predicates.  If the partition key is one of the predicates, the query plan should show that Oracle just has to access a single partition without you needing to specify it.  Unless you've done something like implement manual partitioning rather than range partitioning...

Comment: I don't have partition key in `where` condition, but I have it in `set` clause. You mean, if I use partition key in `where` condition, then I need not bother about partition name? And that the plain `update` statement with `where` having partition key will be efficient?

Comment: No. My `update` statement couldn't use the partition key in `where` clause.

Comment: How can you find the partition then?  If `partition_date between '01-OCT-2015' AND '31-OCT-2015'` gives you the name of the single partition that has the data you are interested in and `partition_date` is the partitioning key, why can't you just add that predicate to your query and eliminate the need to name the partition?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dynamic sql instead of static;
Please find code below,

```
declare
v_date  date:= to_date('01-AUG-2015','dd-mon-yyyy');
bEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT distinct (uo.subobject_name) partition_name FROM parttab t, user_objects uo
     WHERE dbms_rowid.rowid_object(t.rowid) = uo.object_id) LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('update parttab partition (' || i.partition_name || ') set jdate = '||v_date );
    execute immediate 'update parttab partition (' || i.partition_name || ') set jdate = :vv_date' using v_date;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I declared a variable `setter VARCHAR2(20) := '01-AUG-2015'`. I changed my code as per your answer to this one - `execute immediate 'update parttab partition (' || i.partition_name || ') set jdate = (' || setter  || ')';`. This gives `ORA-00904: "AUG": invalid identifier`

Comment: I have assumed that you want update records in table for particular partition say SYS_P3495 in your case;  assuming that you are selection partition dynamically and updating records for particular partition only in this case your sql query will become   update mytable "partition clause" set = " set clause " and then where condition.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your comment. My requirement is simple - In your answer, instead of `sysdate-1`, I want to pass date in `dd-MON-yyyy` format. How to do that?

Comment: for your sql setter VARCHAR2(20) := '01-AUG-2015' should be date  like setter date := '01-AUG-2015' and set condition will become 'set jdate = ' || setter ;

Comment: +1. Now - `execute immediate 'UPDATE MYTABLE partition(' || p_partition_name || ') SET PARTITION_DATE =' || setter || ' WHERE MYSOMECOLUMN = ' || partition_table(i).request_id;` is giving - `00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`

Comment: Please find my update code you need to use using clause for any variable in assignment in dynamic sql.